# Is it legal to statically link libstdc++ and libgcc in a binary-only application?

Tags: c++, gcc, licensing, gnu

Is it legal to distribuite a binary-only application which has been built by statically linking **unmodified versions** of both `libstdc++` and `libgcc` from the `GCC` suite version **4.7** or greater?

Comment: You are asking for an interpretation of the copyright?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no lawyer, but I think that the faqs at GNU are pretty clear on this. Yes you can! But only if you want to distribute executables.

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception-faq.html
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.license.what